# Slide-in menu is pushing other elements away

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-position, overlay

My issue is regarding the menu that slides in when you hover over the "open buttons" It pushes everything down, which is an issue. It is intended to open over the images, and I'm unable to figure out how to do this. I have tried adding things such as floats and altering position tags in the past and nothing seems to have worked. Here is my code:

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#Bar {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 64px;
    background-color: #592881
}

#logo {
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(89, 40, 129, .7);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    position: static;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: grey;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .sidenav a {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}

.fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.slides {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.mySlides {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.prev,
.next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.next {
    float: right;
    top: -500px;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev {
    left: 0px;
    top: -500px;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.footer {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    color: #A8A8A8;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-left: 400px;
}

.overlay {
    float: left;
    height: 70%;
    width: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: .5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 300px) {
    .overlay a {
        font-size: 20px
    }
    .overlay .closebtn {
        font-size: 40px;
        top: 15px;
        right: 35px;
    }
}

.buttonContainer {
    height: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Masters of Engineering</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Zach\Desktop\Coding\Robotics Site\css\Main.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/Corner Logo.ico">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="Bar"></div>
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="https://www.mastersny.org/uploaded/template/default/images/common/logo.png">
    </div>
    <script>
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
    }
    </script>
    <div class="buttonContainer">
        <span style="margin-left:10%;font-size:30px;cursor:pointer; display: inline-block;" onmouseenter="openNav()" onmouseleave="closeNav()">&#9776;open</span>
        <span style="margin-left:10%;font-size:30px;cursor:pointer; position:relative; display:inline-block;" onmouseover="openNav();" onmouseout="closeNav();">&#9776;open</span>
    </div>
    <div id="myNav" class="overlay" onmouseleave="closeNav()" onmouseenter="openNav()">
        <div class="overlay-content">
            <a href="#">about</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="#">Clients</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myNav" class="overlay" onmouseleave="closeNav()" onmouseenter="openNav()">
        <div class="overlay-content">
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="#">Clients</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='slideshow'>
        <div class="slides">
            <img class="mySlides fade" src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/3848765-wallpaper-images-download.jpg" height="auto" width="auto">
            <img class="mySlides fade" src="https://avante.biz/wp-content/uploads/Wallpaper-Images/Wallpaper-Images-005.jpg" height=auto width=auto>
            <img class="mySlides fade" src='https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/vis/a010000/a012000/a012005/Swift_Tidal_Disruption_2_Still.jpg' height="auto" width="auto">
        </div>
        <div class='buttons'>
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusDivs(-1); 
            clearInterval(myTimer); 
            myTimer = setInterval(carousel, 3500);">&#10094;
            </a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusDivs(1); 
            clearInterval(myTimer);
            myTimer = setInterval(carousel, 3500);">&#10095;
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var myIndex = 0;
    var myTimer = setInterval(carousel, 3500);
    carousel();

    function carousel() {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        myIndex++;
        if (myIndex > x.length) { myIndex = 1 }
        x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block ";
    }
    myTimer; //change image every 3.5 seconds
    </script>
    <script>
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showDivs(slideIndex);

    function plusDivs(n) {
        showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function showDivs(n) {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        if (n > x.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
        if (n < 1) { slideIndex = x.length }
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block ";
    }
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class='footer'>
        <img src='http://www.mastersny.org/uploaded/template/default/images/common/bottom-logo.png'>
        <p>49 Clinton Avenue</p>
        <p>Dobbs Ferry, NY 10522</p>
        <p>(914) 479-6400</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In `.overlay` styling use `position:fixed` instead of `position:relative`.